# HTMLUnit rejects a cookie

Tags: java, cookies, htmlunit

I am trying to connect to some website using HTMLUnit library. A problem is that my HTMLUnit client do not accepts a cookie from that site with the following message:

> WARNING: Cookie rejected: "[version:
>   0][name: remixchk][value: 5][domain:
>   .vkontakte.ru][path: /][expiry: Tue
>   Feb 21 08:53:46 MSK 2012]". Illegal
>   domain attribute "vkontakte.ru".
>   Domain of origin: "login.vk.com"

This is because the login form is submitted to the address different from site address.

I need to change a cookie policy in my client. I know, that I should rewrite a `getCookies` method in `CookieManager` class. I have done this in a subclass of `CookieManager` and then changed the `CookieManager` of my client in this way:

```
webClient.setCookieManager(new mySubclassedCookieManager());
```

But this changes nothing. Moreover, when rejecting the cookie the getCookies method never runs.

Where I went wrong? How can I force HTMLUnit to accept that cookie?

Answer (score 1):

You should not change the client : you should change the design of your app. HTMLUnit does what any real browser would do in this case : reject the cookie. A web site may not set a cookie for another domain, for security (and privacy) reasons.

Comment: JB Nizet, actually I log in to that site using any browser. So the problem is inside HTMLUnit.